# Grep repeating patterns with a loop

Tags: bash, grep

I have two files:

file1:

```
ABA
FFR
HHI
HAB
```

file2:

```
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABATRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

Each line in file1 is a pattern that is repeating in the beginning of the corresponding lines in file2. I would like to get the parts of each line from file2 that are not the repeating patterns from file1.

desired output:

```
TRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
DEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
GTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

I tried to use this loop:

```
while read -r line
do

grep -v "$line{1,}"   file2.txt 

done < file1.txt
```

But I go this output:

```
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABATRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABATRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABATRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

Comment: what if the pattern that repeats in the beginning is found somewhere else?

Comment: Is it intentional that file1 contains exactly the same number of lines as file2 and in the same order? Do the patterns in file1 always consist of exactly 3 characters?

Comment: Yes it is possible that the pattern is repeated later.

Comment: File1 and file2 has the same amount of lines in the same order and the pattern is always 3 character.

Comment: `Yes it is possible that the pattern is repeated later.` doesn't tell us what to **do** if that happens. Remove the matching strings? Leave them alone? Something else?

Comment: I need everything after the repeating pattern including any of the patterns if they appear somewhere later in the given line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With e.g. `ABA` in the variable, `grep -v "$line{1,}"` would give grep the pattern `ABA{1,}`, meaning it'd look for a single `A`, a single `B` and then at least one `A`. The last repetition doesn't matter, though, as there's nothing after that, so even a single `ABA` would match that.

Well, except that by default, grep uses basic regular expressions (BRE), where the counted repetition must be written with backslashes, as `\{n,m\}`. In extended regular expressions (ERE), `{1,}` would one or more repeats (and so would `+`); but in BRE, it's just four literal characters (and `+` also is a regular character).

But grep prints full *lines* that match, or with `-v`, don't match; it doesn't remove parts of the line. (Except with `grep -o` where it only prints the matching part, but I don't think that would work with `-v`.) Also, with that loop, `grep` would look at *all* the lines for each pattern, which is why you get the contents of `file2` repeated multiple times.

---

We'd need a loop that reads one line from each input on each iteration. It could be done in shell, but it would be slow. Something like AWK would be better, e.g.:

```
$ awk '{getline pat < "file1"; sub("^(" pat ")*", ""); print}' file2
TRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
DEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
GTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

The AWK program implicitly loops over the lines of `file2` (and other files given on the command line), and here, we explicitly read one line from `file1` each iteration. Then `"^(" pat ")*"` constructs a pattern like `^(ABA)*`, which is matched against the current line, and substituted with the empty string.

This would not remove any instances of the pattern from further in the line, and e.g. `ABAABAFOOABABAR` would turn into `FOOABABAR`. If you want to remove those too, change it to `gsub("(" pat ")*", "");`.

Comment: I seem to recall having used `grep -vo` at least once, and I'm pretty sure it did work as expected.

Comment: @Kevin, well, I'm not even sure what to expect from the combination, really. `-v` says to print lines without matches, and `-o` says to print the matching parts. Their intersection is empty. GNU grep seems to print nothing, but return an exit status based on `-v`; Busybox either printed nothing or segfaulted; and the BSD grep on my mac printed the non-matching lines. So, they basically did the same as `-vq`, or just the plain `-v`.

Comment: IIRC it prints "the part of the line that didn't match," at least on GNU.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `awk` which will remove the repeated pattern from every line in `file1` from the corresponding line in `file2`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pattern[NR]="^(" $0 ")*"; next } { sub(pattern[FNR], ""); print }' file1 file2
```

**Explanation:**

- `NR==FNR` condition that matches the first file only.
- `pattern[NR]="^(" $0 ")*";` construct a pattern from the string and add it to an array using the current line number as the index. `ABA` -> `^\(ABA\)*` = any number of repeated string `ABA` at the beginning of the line.
- `next` skip all further processing. This results in the following action being applied to the second (and following) file(s) only.
- `sub(pattern[FNR], "")` substitute the pattern for the current line number with an empty string
- `print` print the (modified) line

---

A possible solution using `awk` which will remove every pattern in `file1` from every line in `file2`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { pattern[count++]="^(" $0 ")*"; next } { for(i = 0; i < count; i++) sub(pattern[i], ""); print }' file1 file2
```

**Explanation:**

- `NR==FNR` condition that matches the first file only.
- `pattern[count++]="^(" $0 ")*";` construct a pattern from the string and append it to an array. `ABA` -> `^(ABA)*` = any number of repeated string `ABA` at the beginning of the line. `count` will be the number of lines after processing `file1`
- `next` skip all further processing. This results in the following action being applied to the second (and following) file(s) only.
- `for(i = 0; i < count; i++)` loop over all patterns
- `sub(pattern[i], "")` substitute the pattern by an empty string
- `print` print the (modified) line

Comment: instead of `count`, you could use `NR` / `FNR`.

Comment: AWK fields, strings, and generated arrays start at 1, not 0, so you should try to get into the habit of having your user-defined arrays start at 1 too so you don't get tripped up by the difference some day: `awk 'NR==FNR { pattern[++count]="^(" $0 ")*"; next } { for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) sub(pattern[i], ""); print }' file1 file2`. Starting at 1 actually makes some other things easier too, e.g. the very common way of printing the contents of an array `a[]` with `n` elements all on 1 line `for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS)`

Answer (score 1):

Following your approach of a `while read`-bash-loop, `sed` could do the trick as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read pat ; do
    ((i++))
    sed -n "${i}s/^\($pat\)\{1,\}//g;${i}p" file2
done < file1
```

I am a bit confused regarding your interpretation of "repreating pattern", where I assume it should be present at least twice, e.g. `\{2,\}` would feel more fitting to me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, previous steps determine the minimum repeat number in file2. I left it to 1 because this number is not decided yet.

Comment: @Lia in that case, the number may even be a variable: `\{${n},\}` and setting `n` beforehand is fully valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{sub("^("$1")*","",$2); print $2}'
TRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
DEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
GTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

The above assumes neither file contains spaces and file1 doesn't contain regexp metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

There you go mate:

`challenge.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t searchStrs < file1.txt
linesInFile=$((${#searchStrs[@]} - 1))
line=0
while [ ${line} -le ${linesInFile} ]
do
        srchStr=$(echo ${searchStrs[$line]})
        result=$(grep -E "^${srchStr}" file2.txt | sed "s@${srchStr}@@g")
        line=$((${line} + 1))
        echo ${result}
done
```

```
./challenge.sh
TRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
DEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
GTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

```
cat file2.txt
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABATRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

Comment: but the AWK solution above is just pure magic :) I love `awk` but my challenge was to not use it xD

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: You should also copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `sed` and `nl` instead of `awk`. It assumes that the character `#` is never part of the patterns in `file1` and that no pattern starts with a tab character. It will replace the patterns from `file1` only in the corresponding line of `file2`. (`cat -n file1` can be used as an alternative to `nl file1`.)

It uses a single `nl` process and two `sed` processes independent from the number of lines in `file1` and `file2`.

```
sed -f <(nl file1|sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)/\1s#^\\(\2\\)*##/') file2
```

Step-by-step execution instead of explanation:

```
$ nl file1
     1  ABA
     2  FFR
     3  HHI
     4  HAB
```

```
$ nl file1|sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)/\1s#^\\(\2\\)*##/'
1s#^\(ABA\)*##
2s#^\(FFR\)*##
3s#^\(HHI\)*##
4s#^\(HAB\)*##
```

```
$ sed -f <(nl file1|sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)/\1s#^\\(\2\\)*##/') file2
TRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
DEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
GTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

To show that the script will only replace the corresponding pattern, I use an additional `file3` which contains combinations of patterns at the beginning of the lines:

```
ABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAABAHABHABHABTRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFFRFHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
HHIHHIHHIHHIHHIFFRDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
HABHABHABHABHABHABHABHABABAABAGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```

```
$ sed -f <(nl file1|sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)\t\(.*\)/\1s#^\\(\2\\)*##/') file3
HABHABHABTRCFUJIKHRTHVFHJJHVHJJKKHGCC
FHJKGHKKBVDTHJNJ
FFRDEDRJFKOLGCUOUUKJGLNJKKKKJKJKJGGHHBCFDII
ABAABAGTHFOOLLLHHHUUJCIICXXTKCIABAGGC
```